# Are correspondence puzzles on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are correspondence puzzles on-topic?

I mean IQ-test-like tasks like this one [image]

Or "complete the sequence" tasks, like "Complete this sequence of letters o t t ...".

There are definitely have multiply subjective answers, but often people would like to have a help with such a puzzles, this is what this site for.

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer to the question in your picture is G.

Answer (score 2):

> There are definitely have multiply subjective answers

I think you're misunderstanding this a bit. The problem is not whether there can be multiple answers or ways to solve a puzzle, which actually happens quite often. (Otherwise, there would only be one answer per question.)

**The problem is whether an answer can be determined or proven to be *correct***. For example, this is on-topic:

Q: How do I add 12+39?

- A1: You add 10+30=40, and then 2+9=11, and then put them together and get 51.
- A2: You add 12+40=52, and then you subtract 1 and get 51.
- A3: You add 12+30=42, and then you add 9 more and get 51.

and so on. I cannot stress this enough:

## The problem is answer validity, not quantity.

Therefore, yes, these can be on-topic for the site.

Comment: How do you prove that "o t t F" is correct answer?

Comment: Ok. I think one can never define in clear enough way (for me) what is objective and what is subjective, what is prove and what is not... I guess I just should do not care and post what ever I need to ask.

Comment: ITYM “Therefore, no” in the last sentence… most of these puzzles have answers that are as subjective as the “coin in a bottle puzzle”.