# Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions, faq-proposed

My question was closed with the following reason:

> This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers.

The reasoning provided was that it might encourage people to post answers that are either subjectively correct or not demonstrable to be valid. I'm unsure why this is.

Would it be possible to clarify what this close reason means, and how it applies to my question? Why isn’t it on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These types of questions are generally discouraged on Puzzling.SE. There are a few major problems that occur when these questions are asked:

- They can generate answers which are only subjectively valid - that is, to some people, they appear valid, and to others, they do not. An answer is only correct or valid by one’s own opinion, and cannot be determined to be clearly and objectively correct.
- They can generate answers that are objectively questionable - for instance, depending on the country you are in, or a cultural background.
- They can generate answers that depend on different interpretations of the question. In this case, the question may be unclear, or the restrictions and conditions of the question may not be fully defined, which may be able to be fixed by making the puzzle more well-specified.

That being said, if a limited number of answers can objectively be proven to be correct, or are otherwise demonstrably correct, then the question is very likely on-topic. Watch out for questions which have an unbounded or large number of possible answers, as they may fit the above criteria.

If you feel that a question should be considered on-topic for this site, or are still unsure as to how this pertains to your question, feel free to ask here on Meta about your specific question. The community will give helpful feedback where we can!

Comment: On the other hand, if people don't like what you are asking about, they may choose to downvote you for daring to ask, instead of up voting you for having the courtesy to clarify before posting.  On PSE-Meta, there **is** such a thing as a "stupid question."  Be appropriately wary of asking questions here. @Zyera