# Change quality standards auto-check

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since it is possible here to present puzzles, *which you know the solution to*, as chellenge for others quality standards must be changed, because not it is impossible to post short puzzle conditions. The following massage appears:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - *including what you have already tried* - and is written using proper grammar.

This has no sense for challenge-question.

---

Since the other [question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/what-is-formate-for-challenge-questions), about slightly different, but much more important for me aspect, was closed as duplicate I add second part to this question:

1. Please see highlighted phrases above. They disagree with each other. ***Will you do something about this disagreement? If not, how I must interpret it?***
2. How should puzzles, which I know solution to and are challenge for other, be presented here? What is *format*?

Comment: If you're complaining about a question you tried to post, include the exact question body here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated the warning messages about quality standards of questions on PSE](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6813/updated-the-warning-messages-about-quality-standards-of-questions-on-pse) (the older one should be closed in favour of the newer one, since the site has changed so much since this was posted).

Answer (score 1):

No. A good question should have at *least* (emphasis on "at least"):

- Information about the puzzle for people who don't know about this puzzle or puzzle genre
- A description of the puzzle
- A full definition of the puzzle's restrictions, conditions, and specification
- Criteria for a valid solution
- What you have tried already to find a solution (research, etc.)
- Proper spelling, grammar, punctuation, capitalization, etc.

"Puzzle dump" questions that are essentially

> I have this puzzle:
>
> <image or copy/pasted paragraph>
>
> How do I solve it?

are very low quality and should not be posted until enough detail is added.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't this site imply that puzzles here can be posted as a challenge to others? What is a point to say what I did to solve a puzzle if I solved it and others to have fun doing this?

Comment: @klm123 As in posting a puzzle you already know the answer to? In that case, I suppose that item would not be applicable, but it's still no excuse to post a low-quality puzzle dump.

Comment: Yes. And I am asking Exactly about This case and Only about it (see the question). And I would like to get an answer to this very confusing moment, but you do not give it here and closed the other related question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/what-is-formate-for-challenge-questions

Comment: @klm123 The other question has essentially the same answer as this one. Just because you already know the answer isn't an excuse to dump a puzzle with no further description or explanation.

Comment: ok, but I do not see the answer in your answer and comments. They do not explain mentioned disagreement (see highlighted phrase in my question), but completely ignore it.

Comment: @klm123 Again, if you already know the answer, what you have already tried would not apply, but **you still have to post a high-quality question**.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly disagree. If the puzzle you're posting is so short that it gets automatically rejected, then I'm sure it's severely underspecified, and very likely to be [an off-topic riddle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co). Not to mention that the question should generally explain how you tried to solve the puzzle.

Comment: How I tried to solve the puzzle? What is the point to post it then?? Have you seen Challenge tag description? http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/49

Comment: @klm123 Yes, I've seen it. [That tag needs to go](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/burninate-i-know-the-answer-and-i-dont-know-the-answer).