# What is formate for challenge questions?

Tags: discussion

Following the discussion started here: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1277/28

How should puzzles, which I know solution to and are challenge for other be presented here? What is format?

How quality standards, described here:

> Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

is applied to this type of questions?