# What Exactly is Community Wiki Worthy?

Tags: discussion

What would you post to the community wiki? What makes it worthy to be included there? I was just wondering what the standard is.

Answer (score 3):

"Community Wiki" is a vague term. Let's look at the two important parts of it, and the situations in which they help:

- You gain no reputation from it
- It takes *far* less reputation to edit

Thus, it's easy enough to see that community Wiki is designed to be used where an answer is subject to significant community collaboration (which mostly happens on meta), or where an answer should not gain reputation.

---

I have to admit, it's not used a lot. It's been months since I've seen it used well *anywhere*. Because of that, this may be a little vague. Here are a couple examples to better explain the two most common uses:

- A commenter posts a relatively complete answer as a comment, then vanishes. Someone kindly copies the comment into an answer, then flags the comment. But this someone also knows that it really isn't their answer, so they mark it as community wiki (because it came from the community). They won't gain reputation for it, but it gets judged as a normal answer.

  And y'know, maybe others feel they can expand on it, too, and make it a *better* answer. It's the community's answer, now, after all.
- A discussion on Meta warrants a response that should be edited by everyone in the community. Something like, for instance, [what should go in our Help Center](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/what-should-our-help-center-say-about-on-topic-questions?cb=1).

Like the rest of the features of Stack Exchange, Community Wiki is just a tool to help us facilitate better question-and-answer communication. Admittedly, CW is not a frequently-used tool, and in almost all situations it is completely inapplicable. However, in the situations for which it *is* useful, it is *incredibly* so.