# Changing 'joke' to 'humour' or burninating it

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

There have been some posts where I think there have been a few misunderstandings:

Namely:

- [What do you call a cookie without a fortune?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42148/what-do-you-call-a-cookie-without-a-fortune)
- [Which letter of the alphabet is the coolest? Why?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38068/which-letter-of-the-alphabet-is-the-coolest-why)
- [What do you call exactly one kilogram of crows?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41970/what-do-you-call-exactly-one-kilogram-of-crows)

These are some examples of puzzles posted tagged as [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke). True there have been some good ones:

- [3 logicians walk into a bar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12422/3-logicians-walk-into-a-bar)
- [3 logicians walk out of the bar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/three-logicians-walk-out-of-the-bar)

But there is a difference between the two lists. The first set aren't really puzzles, whereas the second set requires something more.

It seems to me that there has been a misunderstanding, especially with new users. The top set where all posted in the first 3 puzzles by the users.

The tag [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke) for me suggests that jokes here are acceptable and counted as puzzles. I want to fix that.

## **I propose we change [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke) to [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) and have joke as a synonym.**

Hopefully that will stop people posting christmas-cracker jokes.

@RandAl'Thor has kindly posted a suggestion for the tag wiki of [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) as an answer but please add suggestions in the comments below it.

@GentlePurpleRain has also made the suggestion that instead of changing the joke tag we get rid of it completely

**Feel free to comment and voice your opinion!**

Comment: +1, good idea. We also need to have a **good tag wiki** for [tag:humour], probably after reaching meta-consensus on exactly which 'joke' questions are on-topic and which aren't.

Comment: Also, I vote to call the tag [tag:humour] and not [tag:humor]! :-P

Comment: @randal'thor, yes, the stack exchange auto correct did that :P

Comment: Another problem with such questions is that they tend to invite unexplained answers. With a proper riddle, a good answer would explain how the solution fits each line. With a 'joke' question, there's not really much to explain, so you tend to get answers like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42150/5373) which are super-short and get auto-flagged for deletion.

Comment: I'll leave this for the mods to sort out

Comment: They (the mods) can sort out the practicalities of merging the [tag:joke] tag into a new tag [tag:humour], but we (the whole community) should reach consensus first! Including on what the tag wiki and excerpt for the new [tag:humour] tag should be, which will reflect the more important issue of the actual site scope when it comes to 'joke' questions.

Comment: @randal'thor, see my answer

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of either a [tag:joke] or [tag:humour] tag.  It seems very meta-ish.  Is anyone ever going to want to search only for puzzles involving humour?  Maybe we should just burninate [tag:joke]?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, I quite like the idea of having 'fun' puzzles. Makes them more interesting. I'd prefer to keep it but just clarify it.

Comment: Although if everyone else agrees with you by all means, ***BURNINATE!*** :P

Comment: I, uh, hate fun.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having fun puzzles, but do they need a special tag?

Answer (score 13):

In the interests of providing options:

#### We should get rid of the [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke) tag entirely.

Most of [the questions with this tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke) are either already closed, or not very funny (obviously subjective).  I don't think the tag really serves a useful purpose, and it should probably just get *burninated*.

Comment: +1 It seems like most of the successful questions there could be (or already are) tagged with wordplay or lateral-thinking instead (and from a linguistics perspective, isn't that what most jokes are anyways? :) )

Answer (score 5):

**I agree with your proposal**: using an adjectival tag will hopefully make it clearer that it's only meant to be used for posting *puzzles* which have an element of humour, not for simply posting *jokes*.

Another problem with the simple joke questions of the 'bad' type you mention is that they tend to invite unexplained answers. With a proper riddle, a good answer explains how the solution fits each line. With a 'joke' question, the text of the question is very short and there's not really much to explain in the solution, so you tend to get answers like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42150/5373) which are super-short and get auto-flagged for deletion.

Realising this enabled me to see *why* such questions are bad: it's the same old "too broad" / "invite speculative answers" close reasons. We can argue until the cows come home about the difference between a joke and a puzzle, and where to draw the line, but most of the jokes can be closed for being not uniquely answerable rather than for not being puzzles.

With that in mind, I suggest the following tag wiki excerpt for the new [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) tag:

> For puzzles that contain an element of humour or wit. Please do not use this tag to post simple jokes which are not puzzles, and remember that questions should be uniquely answerable.

And the following tag wiki:

> This tag is to be used for puzzles that contain an element of humour or wit, or for questions about such puzzles. Questions which are simply jokes and nothing else are likely to be closed if they don't relate to puzzling.
>
> Puzzles should also have a unique, demonstrably correct answer; see [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co) and the associated off-topic close reason. While humour is welcome in puzzles, it shouldn't come at the expense of answerability.

**Suggestions and improvements welcome.**

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, everyone seems to have reached a consensus in chat that we should try [tag:humour] and if it doesn't work burninate it

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Done!  [tag:humor]  I used the American spelling as per [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869).

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I also created [tag:humour] as a synonym, so we can all be happy!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yay! :-D

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little looking at some of the questions tagged [humor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor), I'd suggest what @GentlePurpleRain did in the comments to this question:

## Get rid of both [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) and [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke)!

Take a look at the [list of humor-tagged questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor).  There are only 4 with a QScore of > 10.  The first two are logic problems that have a joke-type setup "...walks into a bar."  If there is actual humour in either, it has evaded me.  The [fourth one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/doctor-who-the-doctor-meets-himself) is actually a decent joke, but is not a puzzle.  The third is the only one where knowing the answer is "silly" might help you.  And onward down the list (there are only 9 more with positive QScores, and 3 of those are closed) you have a mix of non-puzzle jokes and questions with silly/funny answers.

---

From [this SE Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/194181), here are 4 potentially relevant questions about when to burninate a tag.  (I've gone ahead and briefly answered each for the humor tag.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **Is it unambiguous?**

Possibly for the first question, depending on your sensibilities.  And definitely not on the second count.  My sister does not find Monty Python funny at all.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, but not specifically.  I like puzzles with a bit of humour, but humor in and of itself is not on-topic, and having the tag might encourage people who are posting jokes as "puzzles".  "Figure out the punchline" is not really a puzzle.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

This is just my opinion, but almost never.  Like I said, there are one or two examples where it could point you to consider sillier solutions that might help you solve the puzzle, but in general it does not.  And nothing kills a joke like having to point out that it's a joke.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Again, definitely not.  [This whole recent question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42677/the-old-church-from-littlewoods-miscellany) is about people not finding the same things funny.

So I think the [humor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor) (and erstwhile [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke)) tag fails to do anything useful for the site, and in fact might be harmful in that it encourages people to post low-quality stuff that is not really appropriate for the site.

---

## And

There are many playful, funny puzzles on this site already that have humorous elements.  If we're taking a humour tag seriously, shouldn't these all be re-tagged?  Most of the actually amusing/funny ones ([this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17862/an-overheard-gang-meeting-a-double-agent-and-a-murder), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38608/my-jokes-may-not-make-you-smile-but-at-least-my-name-will), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35048/why-is-bob-a-normal-guy), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38816/letter-police-to-the-rescue) (my own)) are not tagged humor.  Retagging these seems like a silly and subjective thing to do.  So let's just **drop the humour tag altogether**.

---

## And

Because I amused myself by alternating between the British and American spellings in this post, do I have to tag it [humor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor)/[humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour)?