# Can there be a tag for “funny” or “nonsense” puzzles?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Some people get fun in trying to solve nonsensical yet imaginative unique puzzles.
So if there was a tag for “funny” or “nonsense” it would avoid irritation caused when user wrongly tags their question as something else.

Answer (score 4):

**What do you mean by "funny" or "nonsense"?**

Tags should always (ideally) have a clear and unique meaning. But all kinds of puzzles can be "funny": it's not limited to any particular genre of puzzle. And a tag for "nonsense" would just encourage people to post complete nonsense that's not a puzzle at all and should be closed and deleted.

### **We already have the tag you want, and we should get rid of it!**

We used to have a [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke) tag, which was renamed to [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) at some point, although the community consensus is actually to get rid of this tag entirely, because it's a breeding ground for bad puzzles. We've been getting lots of low-quality questions with that tag, and it just hasn't worked well for the site. See the previous meta [Changing 'joke' to 'humour' or burninating it](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5430/5373) for more details about that.

As for [nonsense](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonsense) ... that sounds to me like it'd be even more of a haven for bad questions than [joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke)! But it sounds like the existing (and hopefully soon-to-be-non-existing) [humour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) tag ***is*** already the type of tag you're proposing here.

---

Once again, I think you need to be clearer about precisely **what type of puzzles you're trying to describe** in this proposal. Once we have a clear idea of a particular genre of puzzles, preferably with examples, we can discuss how to properly describe and characterise those puzzles, which in turn should lead us to a reasonable name for a tag.

Comment: I was just pointing out the fact that , users would post their question if tag or no tag. But if their was a tag for that topic , it would not catch unsuspecting users who do not like those kind of questions.

Comment: As for some examples of nonsensical type of puzzles [example1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44891/about-a-man-and-a-bee). I am not saying this is bad. But if we see this [example2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46100/dismissing-lewis) , it has been received badly although i feel both examples are of similar type.

Comment: If there was a "nonsense" tag user who use it would target audience who enjoy them, avoiding downvotes and raising flags.

Comment: @Nappa Both of the puzzles you link to already have the [tag:humor] tag. (I didn't realise that tag still existed!) So I think the short answer is **we already have the tag you propose, but we should get rid of it**. It's not a good idea to have a special tag for bad questions, so that they can be seen only by people who enjoy them and avoid downvotes/flags, because generally *bad questions should be downvoted/flagged* even if some people do enjoy them.