# Should multiple-answer questions be marked as too broad?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question

This question is in reference to a question by @JohnS ([SafeCracker #3 - We've Been Blocked](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83525/safecracker-3-weve-been-blocked/83532#83532)). Honestly, *I* don't think it should have been marked as too broad just because there are a couple possible answers. This doesn't mean, at all, that it is too broad, just that more than one user can be correct.

Why was this marked as too broad, and do *you* think it should have been?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is the purpose of the "too broad" close reason here. We even have a custom close reason that may have fit better:

> This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. [See also: Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co)

Puzzles should have a unique solution that clearly fits better than all of the rest, and that does not depend on subjective interpretation. In this question, there are many answers that all seem to be equally valid, and all of the answers (including the 'official' one!) ignore some information in the puzzle: namely, the letters and emoji. This is *exactly* the type of question that the "too broad" and "speculative" answers are for.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the difference between the custom reason and the "too broad" reason? I'm often confused as to which one to use.

Comment: @Brandon_J "Too broad" means "too many possible answers"; this custom reason means "answers are subjectively valid" (which usually *implies* "too many possible answers", but is more specific). After the cross-site change mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291819/close-the-loop-on-too-broad-make-the-close-reasons-actual-intent-reflected-i) though, the "too broad" closure text no longer reflects the meaning as it's used on this site.

Comment: @Brandon_J based on the wording of the close reasons, a "too broad" question might be something like "What's a word game that I can play right now?" while a "off-topic" question might be something like "What's the longest dictionary word?"

Comment: Deusovi and @PiIsNot3 - thanks!