# Are full crosswords allowed here?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I am new here and came across [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91946/elves-hobbits-and-dwarves). I felt it falls in the category of "too broad" of other sites. Am I right in this conclusion, or is it allowed here?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Can you clarify as to why you think that question’s too broad? Which standards from the “other sites” are you applying in your judgement?

Comment: @HTM there are 60+ things to solve there and also I was not sure that's why asked on meta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Too broad" as a close reason doesn't exactly apply here, in the same way it does across the rest of the network.

Some puzzles have many parts leading to a single solution: this is okay. For example, crosswords do have a single final solution (the complete grid), even though there are many small things to answer to produce it. Other types of puzzles, like stacksfiller's [Puzzle in 140 Characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54165/11876), also have many individual components leading to a final answer. These are perfectly acceptable here.

If a question had both a crossword and an entirely irrelevant sudoku puzzle, *then* the 'too broad' close reason might be acceptable. But since the wording changed, the reason has become less applicable to Puzzling.

Our replacement for the "too broad" close reason in most cases is the "speculative answer" custom close reason:

> This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. See also: [Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co)

Comment: Occasionally a post that could be closed as “speculative” is actually closed as “too broad.” I’d say that the two reasons are roughly the same in meaning on this site, with “too broad” also encompassing cases where the asker tries to ask more than one question.

Comment: @HTM I don't think "too broad" is really as applicable to Puzzling, especially since the text for it was redone (twice!): now it's not even called "too broad" anymore, but "needs more focus". Our custom close reason is much more applicable, in my opinion. You'll still see "too broad" used occasionally, especially by people who are used to the old text, but generally the real meaning is expressed better by "speculative answers".