# When are "many" answers "too many"?

Tags: discussion, scope, answers

I know this kind of question is asked before but answers were not clear.

Recently, like yesterday, a nice question, got 18 (and counting) answers! Many interesting, some out there. While I have seen many questions either closed or asked for an edit for even 5 or 6 answers, this one has not drawn any comment. I was under the impression that idea of a puzzle should be to have a unique solution or maybe 2 or 3 possibilities.

What is the criteria for number of answers, if any?

BTW this is not about the 18 answer question. I just need policy clarification.

Comment: There is a mechanism to stop more answers coming in from new/low-rep members: [protection](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). I've never seen it used on Puzzling, however.

Comment: @bobble https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions says we have 404 of them. That link probably doesn't work for you (10k rep is needed), but here's an alternative: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323836/295232

Comment: I can't help but think about how that 19 answer question got closed by the community (5 votes) while nobody in the community thought to close my 11 answer question (got closed my a mod later on) even when my question is *right under* the other.

Answer (score 4):

There is no criteria for the number of answers, though 18 is a bit on the high side. IMHO the main criterion is whether the puzzle has a 'correct' solution which is sufficiently 'obvious' – i.e. one which has that 'aha' moment when you discover or read it.

> This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. See also: [Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254)