# Should I ask for the re-opening of this question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question has been closed an hour ago:

[Reasoning game : The little piglet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117556/reasoning-game-the-little-piglet)

Reason given:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
> This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers. See also: Why are questions off-topic if they invite answers which are not demonstrably correct, or are otherwise speculative?

I read [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) that I could ask you for advice:

> If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site.

The same applies [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co)'s answer, which says:

> Feel free to ask here on Meta about your specific question.

On one hand, my question is fully defined and has one and only one objectively correct answer. I can prove it by giving the answer. I can even give a formal proof by using first-order-logic.

On the other hand, it does invite speculative answers. Some people are not trying to reason, they're trying to guess. I'm not blaming them, it's what I did myself when I first heard it. My first guess was "he keeps the score?" (wrong answer).

So, what should I do?

Comment: Thank you @bobble I'll remember the sign for quotations.

Comment: Update : someone else asked for it to be re-opened.

Comment: The [Reopen votes review](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/53552) has resolved with one Reopen vote and three Leave Closed votes.

Comment: Now someone has found the answer and I posted a proof that the answer was unique and could be found by deduction. Could the Reopen votes reviews please reconsider?