# Shouldn't this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

---

So on October 9th, [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122638/an-anagrammed-logic-puzzle) puzzle by nomad.lw was posted. It currently has 3 upvotes at the time of me asking this question. I have a partial answer on said question (originally posted Oct 11 at 17:50 UTC). Now, for whoever wants to see what the content of the puzzle is without actually going to it, here it is:

> ot rleow utbrctsa aacpilt hwti
>
> dioiadtn het ryou
>
> s-bcBPEDFfJDfeFmksmPOkChDhrgBqjiD-i---ffeNB

Now, the first two lines are easily deducible. They're just anagrams of "to lower subtract capital with" and "addition the your" respectively (unless someone better at anagrams would argue otherwise).

But the third line? That's a jumbled mess that I'm not even sure *how* one would begin decoding it. When I was writing Since I only had what I had, and I didn't want to not post an answer, I just posted this as my partial answer since I couldn't figure out the final sentence:

> Oh. Well, I'll try putting together the (partial) sentence for at least a partial answer here. I won't be able to solve this completely right now, but this is honestly as far as I can go right now. The partial sentence that I have put together so far is
>
> > to subtract the capital ... with ... your ... addition
>
> Note that the ellipses represent that there is something that goes there that I haven't decoded yet, and note that the last two words ("your" and "addition") I don't even know where those will go yet.

The comment discussion on the OG question:

> Would you please be able to give a hint? I feel like it might be confusing to some people how to decode the third line. -CrSb0001 [Oct 12 at 3:36]
>
> it's a riddle + logic puzzle, you've figured out a hint already, work on it! -nomad.lw [Oct 12 at 14:52]
>
> I agree, but here's the thing: How are we supposed to structure the final answer? It honestly doesn't make sense due to there being, once again, no sense. -CrSb0001 [Oct 17 at 15:38]
>
> The answer is in the form of a phrase/sentence -nomad.lw [Oct 19 at 9:04]

That's literally the only hint that was given.

> "The answer is in the form of a phrase/sentence"

No info on any possible way that the 3rd line is decoded. I haven't had a breakthrough while working on the puzzle since I originally posted my answer.

So my question is: shouldn't this question be closed? I feel like this would be [what is considered off topic due to there being no real logical way to deduce the answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7410/are-puzzles-with-the-correct-answer-being-unknowable-allowed) but any feedback on this would be appreciated.