# What exactly is 'too broad'

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

I have read the discussion [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/how-broad-is-too-broad-for-how-do-i-solve-this-puzzle-questions/160#160) and I still have a point to raise. 
I recently posted [a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27877/adding-makes-no-sense) that attracted a lot of attention because of the many creative and amusing ways to solve it. Users were commenting that because of this the question was too broad. If the answers are all unique yet diverse, does that make it too broad?
Surely, too broad means that the question has too many permutations and that any answer given - while technically correct - is simply a bore because there is nothing to distinguish it from another answer (e.g. ways to solve a rubik's cube). However, I think when a question has many **unique** (i.e. creative in their own way) answers it should not be classified as 'too broad'.
What does the community think?

Comment: It's a big frustration of mine - rather than rehash what I already said in the comments of your linked question, I will just note that, despite my repeated asking, no one has ever been able to explain to me what problem they're preventing or solving by closing a puzzle for being "too broad". This indicates to me, increasingly with each unanswered question, that *there actually is no problem*.

Comment: @question_asker thank you. I totally agree... unless there are many indistinguishable yet different answers (e.g. Question: x + y = 200. What is x?). Indistinguishable in the sense that there is no advantage of one answer over the other.

Comment: It just strikes me that we have things like votes and comments to non-destructively show that a question or answer isn't good, why not rely on those *until* an actual problem that we can articulate verifiably exists? Incidentally, justifying closing/deletion with "we don't want future users to be confused" doesn't reflect well on our opinion of potential future users. Why not just walk to their homes and slap them in the face directly?

Comment: @question_asker ...nice. Do you want to formally put forward a suggestion to suspend the 'too broad' option to close a question? I think the problematic cases I described above could be taken care of with "unclear what you're asking" or "off-topic" options just as well...

Comment: The meta post you link to is very old. The scope of the site has changed quite a bit, and that post doesn't address puzzle challenges with many possible answers. A more recent discussion about this kind of puzzle: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/open-ended-questions-inspire-a-vast-number-of-low-effort-answers

Answer (score 9):

Some riddles are fundamentally too broad, and cannot be fixed. For example

> What is black and white and red all over?

It's designed as a pun riddle, said aloud, and the person is actually saying "read" so the answer is a newspaper. But you could answer "a zebra in a blender" or "a referee with a sunburn" or any other number of silly answers. This is not a **puzzle** by the definition of this site.

Other puzzles have a single answer, and when you are exposed to it, you realize that this answer fits all the clues perfectly. Until then there might have been three or four things that sort of fit, but now that you know this one - this is the one!

Sometimes, someone composes a not-too-broad puzzle in their head, but writes the clues in a way that allow many other things to fit those clues equally well. This means they haven't written the puzzle well enough. It's as though they asked

> What food rhymes with blue?

And then were annoyed that people can think of more than just "stew" as possible answers.

The fix is to close, or more correctly to put on hold, which as I have said endlessly elsewhere is a **temporary** action taken to prevent answers from being added **until the question is fixed** and does not mean "go away, we hate you."

If a question is closed as too broad after a number of wrong answers have been added, the asker should reword the clues to constrain things so that, for the food example, the person who was thinking "cashew" or "calalloo" has a way of knowing their guess is wrong. Ideally the clues would actually lead to the answer, not just rule out wrong answers. If a question is closed as too broad before any answers have been added, this is actually better, and the approach is the same - reword the clues to be tighter. (It's harder, because maybe you can't think of any other answers at all, so you don't know why anyone thinks there are any other answers at all.)

Allowing people to ask "What food rhymes with blue" because "too broad" feels hard to define, or it hurts people's feelings to close questions, is not the way to grow this site. It's the way to turn away people who prefer **high quality** questions and answers.

Comment: Who has been turned away by too-broad questions? Can you name one person? On the other hand, though, many people who have had their questions closed have never come back. You can argue that this not the *intent*, but it is absolutely the effect that a minimal-information denial has on people, observably.

Comment: If you don't like the StackExchange model, you don't have to use StackExchange sites. Many Many people have been turned away from many many sites that do not have an emphasis on crisp, clear, **answerable** questions. It's a **feature** of the system. That some people leave because they never learned what was welcome on a site is not ideal, but it's better than being a typical forum swimming in junk.

Comment: As I pointed out, the Stack Exchange model a) explicitly states that multiple good answers are a good thing, and b) *verifiably does not close questions for being "too broad" on other sites to the same extent it does here*. It's not lost on me that you phrased your assertion that people leave because they weren't policed enough as "many many" (despite not having a single example) and referred to the people who left because they were unceremoniously shut out as "some" (and implied that they "didn't learn", i.e., didn't know everything before starting).

Comment: also lol at deleting someone's comments because they call an administrative practice into question. this definitely convinces me that Puzzling is at all interested in the community's opinions.

Comment: I didn't delete your comments, I don't have that ability. And I am not interested in this "name one person! Ha! You can't!" nonsense. The rules of StackExchange don't have to answer to high-school-debate tricks. They are long-established and useful. The population of the Internet is enormous and includes people who don't like them, but that is not in and of itself a reason to change them.

Comment: As for changing the rules, I might be more swayed by your transparent rhetorical tricks if *anyone was even pretending to listen to alternatives*.  And it's hardly a "high school debate tactic" to expect someone to substantiate their claim even a tiny bit, especially when the counterclaim is duly substantiated already. As for the comments, please note that I never claimed **you** deleted them; I just think it's a cute show of force and pulls back the curtain a little on the intentions of Puzzling admins.

Comment: Ok, @question_asker, I'll bite and be that one person, if my personal experience helps... On a QA site where the whole point is to have a single answer get selected as "correct", it's frustrating, as a user, to post an answer that matches the clues and have the OP say, "nope, that's not what I was thinking of, this other person over here gets the tick". Playing "guess what I'm thinking" is not fun. When I see ambiguous/broad questions, it deters me from answering at all, because I don't want to waste my time if there's a dozen equally correct answers...

Comment: And to add to that, questions that are too broad (like the example OP linked) inevitably devolve into either junk answers that lower the quality of the site, or into a "who can be the funniest" competition, which again detracts from the purpose of the site. I'm all for having fun and joking, but a "Base 5031" answer is clearly not a serious one and would be suited better as a comment. It's rules like "too broad" and "subjective" that have saved the SE network as a whole from becoming filled with meme junk that eventually rules most forums without moderation.

Comment: @Alconja The almost-irony here is that I don't really disagree with you. I'm not against "too broad" on the whole, I'm against the way that it's deployed and the degree to which it is deployed, and I'm against not even considering that questions that inspire *creative* answers have value and maybe shouldn't be discarded because it's not as clean a cut as some of the others.

Comment: @Alconja A big part of my problem really is that when asked to justify a "too broad" closure, people resort to characterizing the problem as one of the more obvious cases, and a number of them are not that. We have way more than enough manpower to tackle the trickle of genuinely "too broad" questions that come in, why the weird policey attitude about it? It's excessive, and a big turn-off for lots and lots of people.

Comment: @question_asker - I get your point, some "broad" questions still contain clever and interesting responses that *do* actually add value to the site. The problem (as I see it) is that these broad questions more generally invite an influx of low quality answers, and in turn invite more low quality questions. The line has to be drawn somewhere... This isn't death row, so I'd personally rather lose a few good questions while preventing many bad ones, than to have to continually police all the bad ones claiming, "but they got exemption, why is mine getting closed?!".

Comment: @Alconja Yeah, I get that frustration. I wish we could just be better judges, maybe? I see a lot of stuff where, due largely to the fact that the Puzzling community has not managed to get the answer, stuff gets closed for being too broad, when it's pretty clear to me that there is one answer that *actually* fits (rather than doesn't-fit-but-the-person-posting-it-doesn't-understand-that-their-logical-leap-doesn't-make-it-fit).

Comment: @Alconja and ultimately, this is not like, a website that anyone *needs* - as a totally optional "fun" website, I feel like the attitude here should be more about convincing people they should be here than immediately greeting them with an attitude to implicit distrust inherent in wordlessly closing questions that don't meet an undefinable standard (remember: human communication is fluid enough that, technically, *every* question is too broad)

Comment: @question_asker - Yeah, that's definitely part of the problem... it's hard to fully judge a puzzle when you don't know the solution. That being said, you say it's a big turn-off for people when things get closed, but seeing open ended "puzzles" with no definitive answer is a big turn off for many too (myself included). Puzzles are *meant* to be solvable, which in my mind makes "too broad" even more important on this site than other SE sites... I don't want to waste my time trying to solve a puzzle that turns out to just be a guessing game.

Comment: @question_asker - That being said, I do personally err on the side of innocent until proven guilty. Just yesterday I "saved" [a puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/27927) from being closed.

Comment: @Alconja (sorry for so many comments) see, that's the exact kind of question I'm talking about being more generous toward - if it turns out to be too broad, we can proceed as necessary. In the meantime, let's find out if it has a satisfying intended answer. Literally what would be harmed by that?

Comment: @question_asker - What harm can come? Like I said, I personally dislike having my time wasted trying to solve what appears to be a clever puzzle only to find out that it's just a guessing competition. The problem on both sides (closing vs waiting) is that it's hard to judge a puzzle without seeing the solution. If we close to fast, we might pre-emptively remove good content. If we wait too long, we waste peoples time. I personally would rather lose the occasional good post and improve the overall quality of the site than waste peoples time (especially since gut instincts are usually right).

Comment: @Alconja I'm just on the other side of that. Better one hundred guilty men go free etc. I'm not convinced that the handful of seconds that attempting a too-broad puzzle wastes is time that we actually needed for something else. I mean, we're on a time-wasting website to begin with. Literally none of us are so important that time we purposely, knowingly spend on a leisure website is being "stolen" from us. God, that's such a gross, solipsistic worldview.

Comment: @question_asker ...you're reading way too deeply into how I feel on this topic. Like you said this is a time wasting site, not a death row trial. So why not all collectively try to make this the *best* waste of time possible? And if a few possibly borderline good posts get lost in the process, it's not a huge deal, because overall we've still raised the bar and improved the site, which in turn improves the enjoyment of our collective time wasting.

Comment: @Alconja I mean, it's a moot point anyway—there's no chance the people who have the ability to make the change are willing to, so whatever. I really do sincerely appreciate that you engaged me in good faith, though. It was a refreshing change from the rest of that absolutely exhausting conversation.

Comment: @question_asker - don't we all have the ability to make the change though? No one is governing how/when questions are closed as too broad... I think, unfortunately (based on votes in this post, and in people's close vote actions), you are just on the other side of the line to the majority in this instance. But discussions like this are important to make people think about their power, and maybe you've swayed a few people to your view in the process... Or at least make them think twice before acting.

Comment: @Alconja Somebody (who I won't name because it would be unfair to put them on the spot) once said in a chat discussion that there tends to be a domino effect on these things - so when someone who is especially fond of closing questions VsTC, other people feel the need to  do so as well (especially since there are penalties for voting outside of the popular line, and the fact that we all understand what the popular line *is*). So technically, it's not impossible for all of us to have a say; realistically, however, it's unbalanced in favor of those who have already amassed clout.

Comment: @Alconja This stuff is all pretty well documented in studies of how people respond to power and authority—and when it comes to the semiotics of a closed question, symbols of rejection in general—so the behaviors I'm talking about here are manifest and observable in the world-at-large.

Comment: @question_asker - this is true, but it highlights why discussions like this are important, even if they feel futile. They remind people there are two sides to every issue, with actual people on both sides. And for what it's worth, I vote based on what I believe is "for the greater good", mods be damned. :) (please don't ban me)

Comment: @Alconja They haven't banned me yet, so I think you're safe :) Again, I can't emphasize this enough: thank you for actually taking the time and effort to engage what I've actually said in an honest and good-faith way, rather than just repeating established website dogma at me. I really genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: @question_asker - No worries. Thank you too... Nice when a debate on the internet doesn't devolve into pettiness. ...this is where I compare you to Hitler right? :P

Comment: No, no, this is where you compare _moderators_ to Hitler. Any comparisons of non-moderators to Hitler are disallowed and punishable by immediate suspension.

Answer (score 4):

My opinions may or may not be representative of the community as a whole.

"Too broad" is a close reason for when a puzzle has many possible answers. If there are several answers that are equally good, then I would vote to close as too broad. The puzzle should be constrained so that there is only one possible answer, though it may not be obvious at first. If multiple answers all seem plausible, and nothing's making any of them stand out far above the rest, then I would VTC as too broad.

"Unique" answers don't help fix a bad puzzle. Puzzles' answers should be obvious in retrospect.

---

I feel it is important to have the "too broad" close reason because Puzzling.SE is meant to be a repository of high-quality puzzles (and questions about puzzles). Voting to close as too broad has these effects:

- if the puzzle has potential, then it lets the creator fix the problems and clarify things before it's reopened. They can do this without seeing "junk" answers that are nowhere near what they intended.
- if the puzzle is unfixable, then it doesn't get bumped to the front page because of all the answers that are posted.

Basically, I think "too broad" is necessary because it stops an influx of bad answers to a potentially bad question.

**Puzzles with nothing that makes the right answer any better than other perfectly valid answers aren't puzzles. They're guessing games.**

Comment: Your opinions are representative or my opinions. Solving puzzles is fun. Playing "guess what I'm thinking" is not.